# How to locate modules added from unity hub and delete them

Tags: unity-game-engine, module

I have downloaded some modules from UnityHUB like the below image:

[image: Here is the Image]

Now what I want to do is uninstall those packages like the **WEBGL and WINDOWS** modules as I no longer use this version of unity. How can I locate and uninstall them?

Comment: Welcome to the unity tag, you rarely see questions that don't get downvoted. Not sure if someone dislikes the questions, but then again, most questions can get solved with a short google query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way of uninstalling modules for a unity version, the easiest solution would be do remove and reinstall that unity version.

You can manually remove the folders in:

> \Hub\Editor[VERSION]\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines

But that does not remove unity intern reverences so you are not able to reinstall these modules afterwards and you would need to reinstall the unity version again. So safest and best way would be to completely delete and reinstall that unity version

Comment: On your advice, I tried doing the same but it never cleared the space occupied by the module. Now, what can I do? What I did was uninstall and install a newer version, but the space occupied has doubled and the modules were never deleted

Comment: When you deinstall a Unity version all modules that were installed for that version will be removed as well. Every installed module will only work for the Unity installation where you added it. So you removed the Unity version and reinstalled it and the modules were installed automatically? Because that would not be a normal behaviour. What exactly did double, the Unity installation folder? did you install the exact same version?

Comment: No, I uninstalled unity and then insalled a newer version and added the modules again. (They did not install automatically.) I downloaded the update for 2020 LTS through the update dialogue that appears. (The storage occupied has doubled, the storage of my mac)

Comment: Ok, now you are confusing me. You asked how to deinstall modules, because you don't need them, to do so you removed the unity version and now you download a new version and manually reinstall the modules (you initially wanted to get rid of), what do you even want?

Comment: So what i basically wanted is Uninstall the 2018 version I had because I didn't have space on my computer and then install the 2020 LTS version, since there is very little space on my computer I was space-conscious and asked this.

Comment: So what I didn't want is the 2018 version and what I wanted is the 2020 version.

Comment: well then, removing the 2018 version removes the modules as well, that the 2020 version will be bigger in size has to be expected as there is constant development on unity ;)

Comment: Oh, ok now I get it. Thanks. Could you vote for my question? (of course if you feel so)